# Скрытие меню после скролла в адаптивной верстке

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, scss

В мобильной версии (при малом экране) после нажатия на пункт меню происходит скролл в нужный раздел сайта.

1. Как скрыть развёрнутый список меню с экрана после клика по любому из его пунктов?
2. Как задать координаты места? (куда заскролится экран)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contentSection = $('.section');
    var navigation = $('.nav-wrap');
    var headerNav = $('.nav');
    var clientBlock = $('.client-item-wrap');


    navigation.on('click', 'a', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        smoothScroll($(this.hash));
    });
    headerNav.on('click', 'a', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        smoothScroll($(this.hash));
    });
    clientBlock.on('click', 'a', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        smoothScroll($(this.hash));
    });


    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        updateNavigation();
    });

    updateNavigation();

    function updateNavigation(){
        contentSection.each(function(){
            var sectionName = $(this).attr('id');
            var navigationMatch = $('.nav-wrap a[href="#' + sectionName + '"]');
            if( ($(this).offset().top - $(window).height()/2 < $(window).scrollTop()) &&
                ($(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() - $(window).height()/2 > $(window).scrollTop()))
            {
                navigationMatch.addClass('active-section');
            }
            else {
                navigationMatch.removeClass('active-section');
            }
        });
    }
    function smoothScroll(target){
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. `В мобильной версии (при малом экране) после нажатия на пункт меню происходит скролл в нужный раздел сайта.` Видимо отвечающему нужно проявить фантазию и представить как это выглядит, или вы все же покажите свой код? Хорошо, каков вопрос, таков и ответ: `1.Как скрыть развёрнутый список меню с экрана после клика по любому из его пунктов?` - отследить на JS клики по любому из пунктов меню, затем скрыть развернутый список. `2 Как задать координаты места?` - есть разные варианты, например использовать `scrollTo(pageX,pageY)` или просто добавить якорь в HTML. Минус ставлю, увы.

Comment: @Alexandr Kazakov добавил код. Однако, не уяснил, как "скрыть"  список.

Comment: Благодарю, но этого мало. В вашем задании нужно симулировать ситуацию с меню, для этого нужен базовый HTML и CSS код. В вашем JS коде обработчики клика зарегистрированы на разные меню/блоки, что именно у вас не работает(или работает не так как вам хочется) непонятно. Вам стоит добавить полностью работоспособный и запускаемый код.

Comment: @Alexandr Kazakov добавил headerNav.slideToggle() в событие клика по пункту меню. После клика меню исчезло (как и надо было!). Только теперь при клике на иконку-гамбургер заветное меню не раскрывается обратно!

Answer (score 1):

Вот код скролла до якоря

```html
<section id="Ваш_якорь">Сюда нужно приехать</section>
```

```html
<a href="#Ваш_якорь">Один из разделов меню</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a[href*=#]").on("click", function(e){
    var anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 777);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
});
```

Чтобы по клику по якорю мобильное меню закрывалось, нужно прописать это (bootstrap 4)

```js
$('.navbar-nav a').on('click', function() {
    if ($('.navbar-toggler').css('display') != 'none') {
    $(".navbar-toggler").trigger("click");
```

Comment: последний пункт можете показать с помощью SlideToggle, внедрив его в мой код?  добавил headerNav.slideToggle() в событие клика по пункту меню. После клика меню исчезло (как и надо было!). Только теперь при клике на иконку-гамбургер заветное меню не раскрывается обратно!